# Calculating rolling_std on 4 columns in python pandas to calculate a Bollinger Band?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm just getting into Pandas, trying to do what I would do in excel easily just with a large data set. I have a selection of futures price data that I have input into Pandas using:

```
df = pd.read_csv('TData1.csv')
```

this gives me a DataFrame. The data is in the form below:

```
Date,Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Tick Count
02/01/2013,05:01:00,1443.00,1443.75,1438.25,1440.25,20926,4652
02/01/2013,05:02:00,1440.25,1441.75,1440.00,1441.25,7261,1781
02/01/2013,05:03:00,1441.25,1443.25,1441.00,1443.25,5010,1014
```

Now what I'm essentially trying to do is calculate a Bollinger band in pandas. If I was in excel I would select the whole block of 'High', 'Low', 'Open' and 'Close' columns for say 20 rows and calculate the standard deviation.

I see pandas has the rolling_std function which can calculate the rolling standard deviation but just on one column. How do I get Python Pandas to calculate a rolling standard deviation on the 'High', 'Low', 'Open' and 'Close' column for say 20 periods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can call rolling_std on whole DataFrame or on subset:

```
>>> pd.rolling_std(df[['high','open','close','low']], 5)
```

like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'high':np.random.randint(15,25,size=10), 'close':np.random.randint(15,25,size=10), 'low':np.random.randint(15,25,size=10), 'open':np.random.randint(15,25,size=10), 'a':list('abcdefghij')})
>>> df
   a  close  high  low  open
0  a     16    20   18    15
1  b     21    23   22    15
2  c     20    23   21    23
3  d     19    24   24    17
4  e     23    19   20    17
5  f     15    16   19    17
6  g     19    24   23    19
7  h     21    18   17    22
8  i     22    22   17    15
9  j     19    20   17    18
>>> pd.rolling_std(df[['high','open','close','low']], 5)
       high      open     close       low
0       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
3       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
4  2.167948  3.286335  2.588436  2.236068
5  3.391165  3.033150  2.966479  1.923538
6  3.563706  2.607681  2.863564  2.073644
7  3.633180  2.190890  2.966479  2.880972
8  3.193744  2.645751  3.162278  2.489980
9  3.162278  2.588436  2.683282  2.607681
```

Comment: Thanks - but it doesnt seem to be what i'm looking for. So using what you suggested above I inserted a column to my DataFrame with: df.insert(6,'20SD',0) . Then what I did was try and use you above suggestion to to put the rolling standard deviation into the new column that I created using: df['20SD'] = rolling_std(df[['Open','High','Low','Close']],20)  ...that didn't work and gave this long error ending with "ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, indices imply 4"

Comment: how do you want to put 4 values into 1 column? May be you need 4 columns with std for each of open, high, close, low?

Comment: What I am trying to do is calculate the standard devaition on all selected values over the 4 columns, not just each individual column. In excel I could just use STDEV(A1:D5) to find the standard deviation of all the numbers in that selected block. What I am trying to figure out is how to make pandas/python look at the all the open/high/low/close values going back 20 periods and tell me the standard deviation, not just for the individual columns.

Comment: well the only thing I can think of now is to calculate variances and covariances between each column and then calculate stdev. I'll try to find more elegant solution..